# Weird behaviour of np.sqrt for very large integers

Tags: python, numpy, long-integer, sqrt

```
>>> np.__version__
'1.7.0'
>>> np.sqrt(10000000000000000000)
3162277660.1683793
>>> np.sqrt(100000000000000000000.)
10000000000.0
>>> np.sqrt(100000000000000000000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: sqrt
```

Huh... `AttributeError: sqrt` what's going on here then?  `math.sqrt` doesn't seem to have the same problem.

Comment: Learned something new here.  Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The final number is a `long` (Python's name for an arbitrary precision integer), which NumPy apparently can't deal with:

```
>>> type(100000000000000000000)
<type 'long'>
>>> type(np.int(100000000000000000000))
<type 'long'>
>>> np.int64(100000000000000000000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

The `AttributeError` occurs because NumPy, seeing a type that it doesn't know how to handle, defaults to calling the `sqrt` method on the object; but that doesn't exist. So it's not `numpy.sqrt` that's missing, but `long.sqrt`.

By contrast, `math.sqrt` knows about `long`. If you're going to deal with very large numbers in NumPy, use floats whenever feasible.

**EDIT**: Alright, you're using Python 3. While the distinction between `int` and `long` [has disappeared](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/) in that version, NumPy is still sensitive to the difference between a [`PyLongObject`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/38e263d40d81/Objects/longobject.c) that can be successfully converted to a C `long` using [`PyLong_AsLong`](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#PyLong_AsLong) and one that can't.

Comment: But, but, but, that doesn't explain the `AttributeError` ...  How does that accidentally remove `sqrt` from the `numpy` namespace?  That's gotta be a bug ...

Comment: @mgilson: I was getting to that :)

Comment: (I'm sure this is the reason for the error btw -- But it is a very strange error)

Comment: Oh, interesting.  And since `np.sqrt` is a `ufunc`, a "proper" traceback isn't generated (since the exception is raised in C code).

Comment: Actually, I'm using python3 so they're all `builtins.int`

Comment: The error message is better now - `TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type int which has no callable sqrt method`