# Safety of taking `int(numpy.sqrt(N))`

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I'm considering `M=N**2` where `N` is an integer.  It appears that `numpy.sqrt(M)` returns a float (actually numpy.float64).

I could imagine that there could be a case where it returns, say, `N-10**(-16)` due to numerical precision issues, in which case `int(numpy.sqrt(M))` would be `N-1`.

Nevertheless, my tests have `N==numpy.sqrt(M)` returning `True`, so it looks like this approximation isn't happening.

Is it safe for me to assume that `int(numpy.sqrt(M))` is indeed accurate when `M` is a perfect square?  If so, for bonus, what's going on in the background that makes it work?

Comment: No. If it is a float64, it will be correct to approximately ~20 places which is *a lot*, but not perfect. There are ways to take the int sqrt...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390858/weird-behaviour-of-np-sqrt-for-large-integers and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390807/integer-square-root-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid missing the integer by 1E-15, you could use :

```
int(numpy.sqrt(M)+0.5)
```

or

```
int(round(numpy.sqrt(M)))
```

Comment: Or more explicitly: `int(round(np.sqrt(M)))`

Comment: @RobertKern Thanks. I always wonder why `round()` doesn't return an integer.

Comment: Holdover from C. There are integral `double` values that cannot be represented by any of the C integer types. Python 3.something has fixed that.